# Qt: Space between individual cells in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

(Using Qt 5.5.1 on Windows 8.1)

I have a table displaying **images** selected by the user.

I know their are many other ways to display multiple images on a GUI, **but I'm new to Qt**, so I didn't understand how to use QGraphicsView and found the following to be the easiest way.

But this forms a table in which images are not separated. I want some space b/w them. See how the next images starts right where the first ends.

How can I do it so that next image starts after leaving some space?

I need those checkboxes too (they came bu default by using QTableWidget) because after adding images, I want user to select them too for further processing.

[image]

**main.cpp**

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.jpg)"));
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
QStringList all_filenames = dialog.selectedFiles();
int maxCol    = 3;                         
int maxRows   = all_filenames.size() / maxCol;
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(maxCol);
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(maxRows);
int remainder = all_filenames.size() % maxCol;
if (remainder != 0)
{
   maxRows +=1;
}
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(200);
ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(200);
if(all_filenames.isEmpty() == 0)
{
 for( int i = 0; i < all_filenames.size() ; ++i)
  {
      QPixmap map(all_filenames.at(i));
      map = map.scaled(200,200,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Q::FastTransformation);
      QBrush brush(map);
      QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
      item->setCheckState(Qt::CheckState());
      item->setBackground(brush);
      ui->tableWidget->setItem(j,k,item);
      k++;
      if ( k == maxCol )
      {
          j++;
          k = 0;
      }


  }
}
```

**EDIT**

**cmargindelegate.cpp**

```
#ifndef CMARGINDELEGATE_H
#define CMARGINDELEGATE_H
#include <QItemDelegate>

class CMarginDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
public:
    explicit CMarginDelegate(int margin, QObject* parent);
    ~CMarginDelegate();
private:
    int m_margin;

public slots:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,const QModelIndex &index);
};
 #endif // CMARGINDELEGATE_H
```

**cmargindelegate.cpp**

```
#include "cmargindelegate.h"
#include <QItemDelegate>

CMarginDelegate::CMarginDelegate(int margin, QObject*parent):QItemDelegate(parent),m_margin(margin)
 {}

CMarginDelegate ::~CMarginDelegate()
{}

void CMarginDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);

// Make the 'drawing rectangle' smaller.
itemOption.rect.adjust(m_margin, m_margin, -m_margin, -m_margin);

QItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
}
```

Comment: Does setting a padding with a stylesheet help? `ui->tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item { padding: 10px }");`

Comment: No, that doesn't help. I had tried something similar before : `ui->tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section:vertical {margin-right: 10; border: 1px solid}");`. That also didn't help.

Comment: May I suggest *not* using QTableWidget for this purpose?

Comment: @peppe I understand `QTableWidget` is not a good way, but I am very inexperienced in Qt. Perhaps you could guide me through the steps that use some other widget, some code would be really helpful.

Comment: I would just say: use a custom widget. See one of the examples that involves creating a plain QWidget and drawing in its `paintEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom delegate to draw your table cells. You can start with this one:

```
class CMarginDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
public:
    CMarginDelegate(int margin, QObject* parent)
        :   QItemDelegate(parent),
            m_margin(margin)
    {}

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);

        // Make the 'drawing rectangle' smaller.
        itemOption.rect.adjust(m_margin, m_margin, -m_margin, -m_margin);

        QItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
    }

private:
    int m_margin;
};
```

And this is how to use it:

```
ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(new CMarginDelegate(5, ui->tableWidget));
```

Comment: I could not integrate your code with mine. I made a `CMarginDelegate.cpp` and `CMarginDelegate.h`, included this `.h` in my `main.cpp`. Then did this `ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(new CMarginDelegate(5, ui->tableWidget));`. No results. I have made some edits to my question based on your answer. You may tell my mistake.

Comment: The `QItemDelegate::paint()` is a *const* method, you have to define it properly in your `CMarginDelegate` if you want to override it. And you don't need it to be a slot. Tak a look again on my `CMarginDelegate`.

Comment: The code that you have written, it is to be written in `cmargindelegate.cpp` or `cmargindelegate.h` ?

Comment: You can declare your custom delegate in the .h file and implement in the .cpp file like you did, there is no problem with it. Just add that *const* modifier to the both `CMarginDelegate::paint()` declaration and definition. Or just paste my code into your *main.cpp*, that's the most easiest way.